# How do I decipher the output script one op code at a time

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, litecoin

I have an output script:  OP_DUP OP_HASH160 629dba50de30602afbf52b89bd0de056b0ad0e92 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG

and an input script for a next transaction:  script_asm" : "30450221008d928cf86eec73535e401e22db895f23d2a04ecb355fa3acfaa6c88de278606602200b34186f5bb90023c06f68bc401276ae7db55433eb0e5b5846a0edb3938876e601 026c6090ef2c100a1beea5c0584de29925d070ebc614fd00f52832250c5b66873c

My understanding is that the output script is a set of conditions that have to to be presented to claim ownership of the coins.

Unfortunately, the page here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script
is not very clear as to how the output script is executed step by step.

What I mean is what happens at each stage of these OP codes:
OP_DUP 
OP_HASH160 
629dba50de30602afbf52b89bd0de056b0ad0e92 
OP_EQUALVERIFY 
OP_CHECKSIG

Comment: Doesn't this help? https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/58380c05-2488-4982-800f-56c6453d7acf.png

Comment: @MCCS not really, is there any example out there where I can see thne script in action? Not just the description of the script

Comment: I think what I'm really trying to ask is, how I manually verify the scriptpubkey against the scriptsigkey